# Remplazar los enteros de un json por strings C#

Tags: c#, json

Hola amigos necesito rempalzar todos lo enteros dentro de un **json** por cadenas, de decir que si tengo un objeto como :

> { x : 1 } ... querré tener { x : " 1 " }

pero necesito que lo haga con un json de cualquier tamaño, como por ejemplo

> {"x":2,"y":"GLAN105","z":"2042"},{"x":4,"y":"GLAN425","z":"2042"},{"x":34,"y":"ZLXN425","z":"2212"}, etc ...

No sé si exista alguna función o algo similar que hago de este estilo en C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obten las keys de tu JSON y reemplaza su valor por strings

```
string jsonprueba = "{\"A\": 1,\"B\": 2,\"C\": 3}";
JObject jsonObj = (JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonprueba);
var keys = jsonObj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList(); 
foreach(string k in keys)
{
    jsonObj[k] = jsonObj[k].ToString();
}
var jst=jsonObj.ToString();
// IN:  {"A": 1,"B": 2,"C": 3}
// OUT: {"A": "1","B": "2","C": "3"}
```

Comment: solo tengo una pregunta el formato de un json o al menos del que tengo es algo como > {"a" : 1, "b" : "go"}
entonces como puedo pasarle esta linea a mi bariable de entrada, dado a que es un json muy largo , tendría que hacer un función para agregarle ese " \ " antes de procesarlo?

Comment: las diagonal invertida ( \ )  sirve de caracter de escape para las comillas dobles ( " ) en una string, tener un `\"` es interpretado como un `"`, si  tienes una cadena en formato json que lees de alguna parte, el interpretador de las cadenas se encarga de agregar los escapes correspondientes, en el ejemplo, al crear yo la cadena tengo que escaparla manualmente. Si tu entrada es `{"a" : 1, "b" : "go"}` esta es guardada como `"{\"a\" : 1, \"b\" : \"go\"}"` con las comillas dobles escapadas encerrada dentro de comillas dobles que denotan que es una string.